# Transforming non-normal data to be normal in R

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, mixed-model, glmm

I have gone through a variety of posts and after natural log, sqrt, log10, and inverse transformations, one of my columns in R is not even close to being normal. I want to run a linear mixed model on it.

Here is some of my data:

```
> dput(head(df, 200))
structure(list(meanodba = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0024429845, 
0.0024429845, 0.002844277, 0.002844277, 0.0701741105, 0.0701741105, 
0.003012713, 0.003012713, 0.168142569, 0.168142569, 0.19269525, 
0.19269525, 0.003600107, 0.003600107, 0.003282639, 0.003282639, 
0.006676893, 0.006676893, 0.004318509, 0.004318509, 0.0049651105, 
0.0049651105, 0.052186496, 0.052186496, 0.002547072, 0.002547072, 
0.003099685, 0.003099685, 0.006663461, 0.006663461, 0.002233525, 
0.002233525, 0.002393341, 0.002393341, 0.003468077, 0.003468077, 
0.001722613, 0.001722613, 0.002360538, 0.002360538, 0.006206355, 
0.006206355, 0.002143561, 0.002143561, 0.001891434, 0.001891434, 
0.00230823, 0.00230823), Turtle = c("R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", 
"R3L1", "R3L12"), Time = structure(c(1432339200, 1432340100, 
1432341000, 1432341900, 1432342800, 1432343700, 1432344600, 1432345500, 
1432346400, 1432347300, 1432348200, 1432349100, 1432350000, 1432350900, 
1432351800, 1432352700, 1432353600, 1432354500, 1432355400, 1432356300, 
1432357200, 1432358100, 1432359000, 1432359900, 1432360800, 1432361700, 
1432362600, 1432363500, 1432364400, 1432365300, 1432366200, 1432367100, 
1432368000, 1432368900, 1432369800, 1432370700, 1432371600, 1432372500, 
1432373400, 1432374300, 1432375200, 1432376100, 1432377000, 1432377900, 
1432378800, 1432379700, 1432380600, 1432381500, 1432382400, 1432383300, 
1432384200, 1432385100, 1432386000, 1432386900, 1432387800, 1432388700, 
1432389600, 1432390500, 1432391400, 1432392300, 1432393200, 1432394100, 
1432395000, 1432395900, 1432396800, 1432397700, 1432398600, 1432399500, 
1432400400, 1432401300, 1432402200, 1432403100, 1432404000, 1432404900, 
1432405800, 1432406700, 1432407600, 1432408500, 1432409400, 1432410300, 
1432411200, 1432412100, 1432413000, 1432413900, 1432414800, 1432415700, 
1432416600, 1432417500, 1432418400, 1432419300, 1432420200, 1432421100, 
1432422000, 1432422900, 1432423800, 1432424700, 1432425600, 1432425600, 
1432426500, 1432426500, 1432427400, 1432427400, 1432428300, 1432428300, 
1432429200, 1432429200, 1432430100, 1432430100, 1432431000, 1432431000, 
1432431900, 1432431900, 1432432800, 1432432800, 1432433700, 1432433700, 
1432434600, 1432434600, 1432435500, 1432435500, 1432436400, 1432436400, 
1432437300, 1432437300, 1432438200, 1432438200, 1432439100, 1432439100, 
1432440000, 1432440000, 1432440900, 1432440900, 1432441800, 1432441800, 
1432442700, 1432442700, 1432443600, 1432443600, 1432444500, 1432444500, 
1432445400, 1432445400, 1432446300, 1432446300, 1432447200, 1432447200, 
1432448100, 1432448100, 1432449000, 1432449000, 1432449900, 1432449900, 
1432450800, 1432450800, 1432451700, 1432451700, 1432452600, 1432452600, 
1432453500, 1432453500, 1432454400, 1432454400, 1432455300, 1432455300, 
1432456200, 1432456200, 1432457100, 1432457100, 1432458000, 1432458000, 
1432458900, 1432458900, 1432459800, 1432459800, 1432460700, 1432460700, 
1432461600, 1432461600, 1432462500, 1432462500, 1432463400, 1432463400, 
1432464300, 1432464300, 1432465200, 1432465200, 1432466100, 1432466100, 
1432467000, 1432467000, 1432467900, 1432467900, 1432468800, 1432468800, 
1432469700, 1432469700, 1432470600, 1432470600, 1432471500, 1432471500
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Perc.activ = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 
66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 
66.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 
16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 
16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 
16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 
16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 16.66666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -200L), groups = structure(list(
    Turtle = c("R3L1", "R3L12"), .rows = structure(list(c(97L, 
    99L, 101L, 103L, 105L, 107L, 109L, 111L, 113L, 115L, 117L, 
    119L, 121L, 123L, 125L, 127L, 129L, 131L, 133L, 135L, 137L, 
    139L, 141L, 143L, 145L, 147L, 149L, 151L, 153L, 155L, 157L, 
    159L, 161L, 163L, 165L, 167L, 169L, 171L, 173L, 175L, 177L, 
    179L, 181L, 183L, 185L, 187L, 189L, 191L, 193L, 195L, 197L, 
    199L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
    37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
    49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
    61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
    73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
    85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
    98L, 100L, 102L, 104L, 106L, 108L, 110L, 112L, 114L, 116L, 
    118L, 120L, 122L, 124L, 126L, 128L, 130L, 132L, 134L, 136L, 
    138L, 140L, 142L, 144L, 146L, 148L, 150L, 152L, 154L, 156L, 
    158L, 160L, 162L, 164L, 166L, 168L, 170L, 172L, 174L, 176L, 
    178L, 180L, 182L, 184L, 186L, 188L, 190L, 192L, 194L, 196L, 
    198L, 200L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

You can see here that my data is not near a normal distribution

```
hist(df$meanodba)
```

[image]

After all of my transformations, the data still didn't looking normally distributed, or even close. What do I do now? I know there is the Box-Cox transformation, but can that be transformed for just one specific column?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can apply differnt transformations to different features, sure. However, normality is less important than it seems. Why do you want to transform at all? There is no assumption of feature normality. (That would make it rather tough to do ANOVA.)

Comment: The Box-Cox transformation is univariate: one *number* goes in, another number comes out.  You *can't* apply it  to more than one column except separately in each column.  And no, there's no requirement that all columns be transformed when one is.  If that were the case, how would you handle a model in which (say) mass and pH (a log activity) were both included??

Comment: Are you talking about the response or a covariate?

Comment: @Dave I had assumed that the normality assumption needed to be fit for Linear Mixed Models.

Comment: @Michael M, to clarify meanodba is the response variable. There are many other factors involved but for to simplify the data set, I didn't include them.

Comment: There is no assumption of marginal normality, either. It is a common misconception that the raw $y$ variable should be normal.

Comment: @Dave: model effects are often too small to turn heavy marginal skew into conditional normality. Furthermore, mixed models might react to non-normality worse than a usual regression.

Comment: Before fitting any models, I would take a careful look at the data. Turtles "R3L12" and "R3L1" have exactly the same values for `meanodba` which is strange to say the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Linear Mixed Model Assumptions

You do not need to do all that. They key here is to try to have normal *residuals*, not normal raw data. See below from Meteyard & Davies, 2020:

[image]

It appears that at least your data is heavily right skewed, so you can at least see what your data is doing when fitting it first (it's not obvious what your model is, but it appears your meanodba variable is at least the DV). If the fitted residuals look abnormal, then you can instead fit the mixed model to the proper `family` argument in the `glmer` function from the lme4 / lme4Test packages. You can consider instead other GLMM families to use such as inverse Gaussian, beta, Poisson, or other right-skewed GLMM families.

##### Worked Example in R

As an example, I have fit a dataset in lmerTest called `carrots` in the R program.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lmerTest)
library(performance)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- lmer(Preference 
            ~ sens2 
            + Homesize 
            + (1 + sens2 | Consumer),
            data=carrots)
```

Then plot the residuals with a density plot:

```
#### Plot Residuals ####
plot(density(resid(fit)))
```

Shown below:

[image]

Then I check the distribution of the fit thereafter to make sure it is at least close:

```
#### Check Distribution ####
plot(check_distribution(fit))
```

[image]

##### Final Note on Switching to GLMM (If Needed)

From here we can assume the normality of residuals assumption has been met. However it is likely your fit won't be this way. For an example of how to do a non-normal GLMM, [here is an example using logistic GLMMs](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/) and an example using a [Poisson GLMM](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-poisson-regression-in-r/). You may also check out the [glmmTMB package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/glmmTMB.pdf)  for additional families like the beta distribution.

Comment: Thank you so so much for this detailed explanation. I had no idea that for linear mixed models the response didn't have to be normally distributed. As you guessed, my residuals were not normally distributed so on to glmm! Follow up question, is glmer basically like lmer but it's for non-normal data? Can I treat that function the same way?

Comment: @Cassidy If you haven’t studied generalized linear models like logistic regression, my suggestion is to change that before you dive into generalized *mixed* models.

Comment: @Dave, yes that would be a good idea but for this research, I have to use a random variable which would push me to use a mixed model set up. Without the random variable, there basically would be no project.

Comment: @Cassidy Random *variable* or random *effect*?

Comment: @Dave sorry, random effect

Comment: And I don't mean that you should try a fixed-effects-only generalized linear model (GLM). I mean that, if you are unfamiliar with how GLMs work, I advise that you learn about them before you try to tackle mixed-effects GLM (generalized linear *mixed* models, GLMMs).

Comment: @Cassidy yes glmer is basically just a more flexible version of lmer. The syntax is pretty similar. And as Dave suggested, it would be wise to get a good understanding of GLMs before moving to GLMMs

Answer (score 3):

Presumably there is biological context here to inform choice of transformations as well as choice of model, but on that I am totally (turtlely? (*)) ignorant.

You give 48 values of `meanodba` to work with. I just want to flag that reciprocals work quite well to make the distribution more symmetric. How useful that is in the context of a mixed model I cannot say. There is often some scientific or practical basis for using a reciprocal (times and rates are reciprocal; miles per gallon might be better as gallons per mile, or some multiple; people per unit area could be area per person; and so on).

As others have pointed out, there is no assumption of normality for what you are doing, but getting closer to it can help in other ways.

Here are normal quantile plots for original, logarithm and reciprocal scales.

Naturally reciprocals flip order -- the smallest value becomes the largest reciprocal -- and because of that some people prefer to negate them. In the graphs, note how the 8 moderate outliers are pulled in but move from top right to bottom left from the first panel (Original) to the last (Reciprocals).

Note 1: Box-Cox (noting its wonderful name) as an automated procedure seems to me over-rated and over-used. Their original 1964 paper went beyond Tukey's work to emphasize that many common transformations, powers and logarithms, belong to a single family of transformations when suitably parameterized. They also pushed the idea that the data can be used to find a good transformation. But in their worked examples they chose logarithm and reciprocals as simple transformations that made sense any way. It isn't often helpful, let alone necessary, to choose some arbitrary power such as .123 or .345.

Note 2: I am not related to Sir David Cox, the Cox in question.

[image]

(*) Any pun on "total" and "turtle" works best, and perhaps only, in North-East England.